# How can I turn off my internet connection from the terminal window without using sudo?

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, calabash

From OSX, I need to do something to temporarily simulate wifi going down on my iOS device while running a test (via the Calabash framework). I can't shut off the actual wifi because Calabash needs that connection to run the tests.

I thought about blocking ports, but haven't found a non-sudo way to do this. I cannot use sudo because the tests have to run in the lab without human interaction. I know a common workaround is you can add the user to the wheel group, but in doing so it reduces the security of the machine that does it. I'd really like to avoid introducing security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to one of the creators of Calabash:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/calabash-ios/jkoN2ztJ9QI  So it's possible, just not very easy

Comment: Thank you! I searched the forums there but never saw that thread.